# Consul vs API Gateway

Tags: api, consul, api-gateway

I would like to ask about the functionalities of Consul and API Gateway. Is Consul can replace API Gateway as a service referrer ?

Or how to use both of them in term of microservices architecture ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Consul is multi datacenter service discovery (+health checking) and distributed K/V store.

API Gateway is a service that handles all the tasks involved in accepting and processing API calls, including traffic management, authorization and access control, monitoring, and API version management.

so they're quite different..

depends on what you're trying to achieve and your current API Gateway use case, you may be able to use Consul + Consul aware load balancers, such as https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio and https://traefik.io/.

Comment: consul is also  a service mesh

Answer (score 2):

At a high-level, an API gateway would become the single point of entry to your micro services. It would allow you to give a consistent user experience to your clients - irrespective of the backend services.

They act as an abstraction - when you hit a `/product/{productId}` endpoint, you shouldn't need to know about the internal microservices e.g. `/reviews`, `/recommendations` etc - the gateway can do this for you and return a single response.

API gateways will be configured to receive a request on a listen path e.g.

`curl http://gateway.com/myservice/mypath -H 'Authorization: secret_auth_token'`

Internally, the gateway will receive the request and will see that `myservice` points to a specific api definition.

And based on that auth-token, will be able to establish whether the user is allowed access, what rate limit / quotas and also what upstream targets & paths they are allowed access. A few typical features:

- Authentication & Authorisation
- Rate Limits
- Body Transforms (Filters / Map Reduce / Json -> XML, XML -> Json)
- Header Injection
- Json Schema Validation
- Method Transforms
- Mock Responses
- API Versioning Strategy
- Send requests to multiple targets
- the list goes on.

So the gateway will then proxy the request to `myservice.com/mypath` for example and return the response to the client.

Now let's assume you want your upstream to be highly available - e.g. you may have `myservice1.com` and `myservice2.com`.

The gateway can be configured to load balance requests between these services. And you could use features of the gateway for testing the health of the upstreams, but there are also dedicated tools for this. One such tool is Consul.

API gateways should be able to integrate with service discovery tools. So let's assume `myservice1.com` goes down for maintenance, the gateway will know never to send traffic there and to only send to `service2.com` till service1 comes back up.

Screenshot below is example of tyk.io api gateway integration support for Consul.

[image]